# Wildfly Server shutdown after wildfly:start

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm trying to use Wildfly Maven Plugin and when I use wildfly:start command, it generates the follow log:

```
[INFO] JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
[INFO] JBOSS_HOME=D:\dev\projects\untitled4\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-10.0.0.Final

[INFO] Server is starting up.
fev 21, 2016 12:11:04 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
fev 21, 2016 12:11:04 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
fev 21, 2016 12:11:04 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
00:11:04,998 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
00:11:06,181 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
00:11:06,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
00:11:10,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
00:11:10,594 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
00:11:10,598 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
00:11:10,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
00:11:10,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
00:11:10,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
00:11:10,623 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
00:11:10,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
00:11:10,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
00:11:10,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
00:11:10,689 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
00:11:10,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
00:11:10,711 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
00:11:10,713 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
00:11:10,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
00:11:10,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
00:11:10,750 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
00:11:10,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
00:11:10,758 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
00:11:10,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
00:11:10,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
00:11:11,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
00:11:11,147 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'D:\dev\projects\untitled4\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
00:11:11,150 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
00:11:11,151 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
00:11:11,173 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
00:11:11,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\dev\projects\untitled4\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
00:11:11,303 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
00:11:11,303 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
00:11:11,303 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
00:11:11,892 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
00:11:11,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
00:11:11,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
00:11:11,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 7601ms - Started 267 of 553 services (371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:56.416s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 21 00:11:14 BRT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Few seconds later, without my interaction:

```
00:11:14,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0211: Suspending server with 0ms timeout.
00:11:14,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
00:11:14,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
00:11:14,930 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
00:11:14,933 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
00:11:14,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
00:11:14,935 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
00:11:14,936 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.3.15.Final stopping
00:11:14,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) stopped in 17ms
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

And the server goes down. 
Someone already got this problem?

I'm not using databases or any other AS features but JAX-WS for some RESTful tests.

Answer (score 1):

The `start` goal isn't designed to keep the container running. It shuts down when you issue the `shutdown` goal or maven exits. There is however an open [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-1) to allow the process to keep running.

Comment: I found this JIRA earlier today. Is wrong to use wildfly:start only to set up dependencies and then use wildfly:run to start the server?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by " to set up dependencies"?

Comment: Sorry... resolve dependencies (download wildfly server dist)

Comment: Ah. The `run` goal will also download WildFly if that's what you're after.